# create Composite-keyed Table with cassandra-cli

Tags: php, cassandra, cql3, cassandra-cli

i want to use php for my project with phpcassa which doesn't support cql, so if I understood right I have to code cassandra commands like I would with cassandra-cli.

> My question is how can I create a Composite-keyed Table or Dynamic Column Families like in this [website](http://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/composite_keys_in_cassandra), though not with cql but with cassandra-cli and where can I find more information about this language.

Comment: You can of course, just use a different PHP client, like http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/

Answer (score 0):

```
create column family myColumnFamily
        with key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(UUIDType,UTF8Type)'
        and comparator = 'CompositeType(LongType,UTF8Type)'
        and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
```

The above command creates

1. A column family named *myColumnFamily*
2. With composite row key of type **UUID:String**
3. With composite column name of type **Long:String**
4. With value of type **String**